# SQL single-row subquery returns more than one row?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I'm trying to get ID and USER name from one query but at the same time I'm looking in my WHERE clause if ID exist in other table. I got error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

Here is how my query look:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.LASTFIRST
From USERS s
Left Outer Join CALENDAR c
On s.ID = c.USERID
Where c.SUPERVISOR = '103'
And TO_CHAR(c.DATEENROLLED,'fmmm/fmdd/yyyy') >= '4/22/2016'
And TO_CHAR(c.DATELEFT,'fmmm/fmdd/yyyy') <= '4/22/2016'
And s.ID != (SELECT USER_ID
             From RESERVATIONS
             Where EVENT_ID = '56')
```

My query inside of where clause returns two ID's: 158 and 159 so these two should not be returned in my query where I'm looking for s.ID and s.LASTFIRST. What could cause this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `not in` instead of `!=`

`!=` or `=` are for single IDs and values, `not in` and `in` are for multiple

```
And s.ID not in (SELECT USER_ID
                 From RESERVATIONS
                 Where EVENT_ID = '56')
```

**Edit: `not in` vs `not exists`**

`Not exists` is a perfectly viable option as well.  In fact, it is better to `not exists` than `not in` if there are the possibility of `null` values in the subquery result set - In Oracle, the existence of a `null` will cause `not in` to return no results.  As a general rule, I use `not in` for ID, not null columns, and `not exists` for everything else.  It may be better practice to always use `not exists`... personal preference I suppose.

`Not exists` would be written like so:

```
SELECT s.ID, s.LASTFIRST
From USERS s
Left Outer Join CALENDAR c
On s.ID = c.USERID
Where c.SUPERVISOR = '103'
And TO_CHAR(c.DATEENROLLED,'fmmm/fmdd/yyyy') >= '4/22/2016'
And TO_CHAR(c.DATELEFT,'fmmm/fmdd/yyyy') <= '4/22/2016'
And not exists (SELECT USER_ID
               From RESERVATIONS r
               Where r.USER_ID = S.ID
               And EVENT_ID = '56')
```

**Performance**

In Oracle there is no performance difference between using `not in`, `not exists` or a `left join`.

*Source* : https://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

> Oracle's optimizer is able to see that NOT EXISTS, NOT IN and LEFT JOIN /  IS NULL are semantically equivalent as long as the list values are declared as NOT NULL.
>
> It uses same execution plan for all three methods, and they yield same results in same time.

Comment: `not in` is slow.  There are faster ways to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

This is a formatted comment that is not related to your question.

This is slow:

```
And TO_CHAR(c.DATEENROLLED,'fmmm/fmdd/yyyy') >= '4/22/2016'
```

because you are filtering on a function result.

This is logically equivalent and much faster:

```
And c.DATEENROLLED >= to_date('4/22/2016','fmmm/fmdd/yyyy')
```

**Edit starts here**

Aaron D's answer says to use `not in`.  Here are two faster ways to do the same thing:

```
left join reservations r on s.id = user_id
and r.event_id = '56'
etc
where r.user_id is null
```

or

```
where s.id in 
(
select user_id 
from reservations
minus
select user_id 
from reservations
where event_id = 56
)
```

Comment: your recommendation is to move event_id after left join instead of having it in subquery? Is that more efficient or ?